# ASP application using the saved credentials even after the user cleared the username and password textboxes and hits submit

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, forms

Could anyone please help, I have an asp application that asks for username and password in the login.aspx page and after logging in with the correct credentials, it prompts me whether to save the credentials. I clicked yes and after some time I logged out, then it takes me to the login.aspx page with the (saved) username and password already filled automatically in the boxes(because I saved previously above). Now my problem is that, now I cleared the username and password that are filled automatically in the boxes and hit submit. Then it should ask for username and password, but now actually it is using the old saved username and password and logging into the application !!!!

*To make it more brief and clear, this is the problem :-

***"I am able to login even though I have removed the username and password.  I logged out.  Erased the content of both fields and then clicked 'Submit'.  I was able to get into the Application."***

```
      Could anyone help please .  Thanks in Advance !!!!
```

Here's my code for the 'Submit' button 'OnClick' Event :-

> ```
> Protected Sub SignIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
> ```

```
    StatusText.Text = String.Empty
    Dim Name As String = UserName.Text
    Dim Password As String = UserPassword.Text
    If IsValid Then
        Try
            Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
            Dim userManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)

            userManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            userManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 7

            Dim user = userManager.FindByName(Name)
            If user IsNot Nothing Then
                If userManager.IsLockedOut(user.Id) Then
                    StatusText.Text = String.Format("Your account is locked. please contact administrator.")
                Else
                    If userManager.CheckPassword(user, Password) Then
                        userManager.ResetAccessFailedCount(user.Id)
                        If Not userManager.GetLockoutEnabled(user.Id) Then
                            userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, True)
                        End If
                        Dim tkt As FormsAuthenticationTicket
                        Dim cookiestr As String
                        Dim ck As HttpCookie
                        'Add Session to 5 Hours 
                        tkt = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), RememberMe.Checked, "")
                        cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt)
                        ck = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr)
                        If RememberMe.Checked Then
                            ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration
                        End If
                        ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                        Response.Cookies.Add(ck)

                        Dim strRedirect As String
                        strRedirect = Request("ReturnUrl")
                        If strRedirect Is Nothing Then
                            strRedirect = "default.aspx"
                        End If

                        Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("adjusterId", New ContextProvider().GetAdjusterId(user.Id)))
                        Response.RedirectPermanent(strRedirect)
                    Else
                        userManager.AccessFailed(user.Id)
                        If userManager.IsLockedOut(user.Id) Then
                            StatusText.Text = String.Format("Your account is locked. please contact administrator.")
                        Else
                            StatusText.Text = String.Format("Invalid username or password, you have {0} more login attempt(s) left before account is locked out.", (3 - userManager.GetAccessFailedCount(user.Id)))
                            StatusText.Visible = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                StatusText.Text = String.Format("Invalid username or password.")
                StatusText.Visible = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            StatusText.Text = String.Format("Unable to login, please contact administrator.")
        End Try
    Else
        StatusText.Text = String.Format("Enter username or password.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: please check [ask]

Comment: Do you have client side validation on the form?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya, ThankYou,   yes I have client side validation on the form for both the username and password textboxes. Ok, to make it more clear to you let me briefly put my problem once again please,  "I am able to login even though I have removed the username and password.  I logged out.  Erased the content of both fields then hit Submit.  I was able to get into the Home screen."

Comment: I believe that the application is still using the saved username and password from the cookie or cache or whatever, I am not sure and not able to find out how to stop the application from using the saved credentials and validate only from the textboxes !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of banging, I found out a simple change that fulfilled my requirement, I just added the below properties for my 'username' textbox in .aspx as below :-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="295px" AutoCompleteType="None"  EmptyMessage=" "></asp:TextBox>
```

(added AutoCompleteType and EmptyMessage).
Not sure whether that's the right approach, but that helps !!!! ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the authentication cookie is being remembered, after the initial login, and that still exists. 
Somehow when you attempt to login with empty fields, it just uses the cookie instead of the empty fields. That would be my guess.

my best guess is that this method is where you will find the culprit code:

```
userManager.AccessFailed(user.Id)
```

It could also be a redirect problem. That you simply attempt to redirect the user back to a page on an invalid login, and since the cookie is still set, you are allow to see whatever page you are getting redirected too.

Main problem, your logout function doesn't remove the authentication cookie.

Comment: Hi Morten, this is my markup on .aspx for the logout :-      
 <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus" runat="server" onloggedout="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut" />

Comment: And Here's my logout function. Am I missing out something that clears the authentication cookie ?? 
   Protected Sub LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
       Session.Abandon()     
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut()     
       Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, [String].Empty)     
       cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)     
       Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)     
       Response.Cookies("adjusterId").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)     
       Response.RedirectPermanent("~/login.aspx")     
   End Sub

Comment: Please Advice, ThankYou !!

Comment: And Here's my logout function. Am I missing out something that clears the authentication cookie ??            >Protected Sub LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
       Session.Abandon()     
       FormsAuthentication.SignOut()     
       Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, [String].Empty)     
       cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)     
       Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)     
       Response.Cookies("adjusterId").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)     
       Response.RedirectPermanent("~/login.aspx")     
   End Sub

Comment: Could any one help me out !  ThankYou.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387488/remove-or-reset-cookies

I would try what this thread suggests in order to validate your cookie has been removed. (Or simply check the browser memory after a logout to verify its gone.

If you have destroyed the cookie, then it is indeed extremely strange that you can re-log. 
. 
With these two threads, you should be able to either solve or debug yourself to, the solution?

Comment: Perhaps the values are stored in a session, but this also seems unlikely. Your response here didn't really format the code nicely, so its a little hard for me to read your code example provided.

But do try and read the thread I linked to. 
FormsAuthentication.SignOut() Should always kill the cookie it has stored, but check in:

https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajfi

for how to check on your cookies

Comment: Just asking because I wouldn't be helping if I wasn't, but are you sure your  password to user method actually validates the password? And not just takes the first user in a table or first match of username in a table?

Comment: (I am not being patronizing, These are all errors I have made myself in the past)

Comment: ThankYou Morten !  I'll try out depending on the given advise .